# Handling token or save from cookie in gatling

Tags: cookies, save, token, gatling

Sorry for my english.
I am completly new at scala and gatling, but i need to handle session token.

```
"X-Auth-Token" -> "62421ead-4gg6-432a-8fb8-def6b8204a72"
```

example of token.

Now i know that token is save in cookie, but i don't know how to save and reuse this cookie. Cookie name is "authToken". I tried to do this:

```
.post("/xxx/yyy/login/authenticate")
.headers(headers_16)
.body(RawFileBody("RecordedSimulation_0016_request.txt"))
.check(headerRegex("Set-Cookie","(.*)").saveAs("authToken"))
```

but gatling found nothing.
Tomorow I will know how token is sending from website, but i also tried to save it from HTTP headers and meta tags:

```
.check(regex("""<meta content="(.*)" name="X-Auth-Token">""").saveAs("auth_token"))
.check(header("X-Auth-Token").saveAs("token")
```

Does cookie have to be downloaded in moment of its saving or can it be downloaded later?

Sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 3):

To save cookie value into session use something like this. Ensure the auth token is coming in the response. Adjust the regex accordingly. To check how it is coming in the response you can test your url in the browser and using dev tools check the response headers.

`.check(headerRegex("Set-Cookie", "X-Auth-Token=(.*)”).saveAs("authToken"))`